# BinaryJedis never returns desired value

Tags: arrays, redis, binary, jedis

I'm setting the pair key and value and then trying to get the value by key.
Here is my code:

```
BinaryJedis binaryJedis = new BinaryJedis(redisUrl, redisPort, 60000);
byte[] data = new byte[dataSize];
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
byteBuffer.putInt(new Random().nextInt());
boolean flag1 = binaryJedis.set(byteBuffer.array(), data).equals("OK");
byte[] values = binaryJedis.get(byteBuffer.array());
boolean flag2 = Arrays.equals(values, data);
```

flag1 is always true, however flag2 is always false.
values equals {0}

I don't understand why it doesn't work, can you please help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try it again as I'm able to get *true* for both of your *flag1* and *flag2*. Randomly, I've tried using `dataSize = 5`. 
If this is happening for any specific case then please specify that case.